# Looking for an answer in regards to POSSIBLY a present perfect in a first conditional sentence

Tags: conditionals

My question is about this one sentence which has been driving me crazy. I found a discussion on here about present perfect in a first consditional sentences. "If I've...., I'll be able to, etc.." But my sentence starts with not an "If", but with "When" it goes: "When I've saved another 1000 Euros, I'll be able to buy a car."

I don't understand how exactly the two tenses here are connected and why can't we say "When (or once) I save another 1000 Euros, I'll be able to buy a car"?

Comment: On the day you are able to afford the car, you will be able to say "I _have saved_ that 1000 Euros".

Comment: Thank you Kate. But could you tell me what tense(s) are these together? I'm a beginner English turor and I need to explain it to a student.

Comment: _When_ referring to the future is the same as _if_; the future is always conditional. As to tenses, all the verbs in that sentence are present tense. _Have_ is present tense, and so is _I'll_, short for _I will_. _Will_ is not the future tense, but rather a modal auxiliary, and therefore doesn't have a past, participle, or infinitive form, only an uninflectable present. _Have saved_ is a perfect construction (perfect is not a tense but a construction; the tense goes on _have_, which is present tense) in the present tense, so it can be called present perfect.

Comment: As for "first conditional", that's something local that some English teachers talk about, but linguists never do. There is no standard numbering, and no limitation to conditionals. The _Nth Conditional_ just means some teacher somewhere put together N easy cases where the meanings can be explained. That doesn't mean there are only _N_ of them, however. And the numbers never match from different countries. So if you're puzzled, join the club.

Comment: Thank you John!